# Loading unclaimed graphic card in Ubuntu 21.10 on iMac 2011

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, mac, amdgpu

On an `iMac 21'' Mid 2011` my `AMD GPU` seems to have gone bad and not able to boot `macOS`, I am now booted into an `Ubuntu 21.10` usb with persistent filesystem and can see both the cards in terminal. The question is how to load the `Intel` card instead of current `llvm` used by Ubuntu, I have tried the GRUB `modeset` options for both AMD and Intel but they do not work and result in black screen, probably because of how macOS handle hardware access.

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a8800000-a881ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:a8820000-a883ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: Display controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:a8000000-a83fffff memory:a0000000-a7ffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```